# ZingChart not supporting utf characters at wordcloud chart( tag chart)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts, zingchart

You can see demo fiddle from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzr80erh/1/);

```
{
    "type":"wordcloud",
    "options":{
    "text":"...", /*text takes string values from REST so dont wanna manipulate it*/
    "step-angle":45,
    "step-radius":50
  },
}
```

As you can see all russian and chinese words in addition to them some turkish characters are not working in this demo. i dont want to change my chart type because i used to be on with highcharts. d3 maybe the best solution but its too much work to me because we have too much charts.

Characters which are not working : ç,ı,ğ,ş,ü all russian and chinese

Answer (score 3):

ZingChart support team replied my e-mail today. They solved this issues. Here is a solution;

```
jsfiddle.net/Lzr80erh/1/
```

They add a new feature to zingchart library such as;

```
var myconfig = {
    "graphset":[
     {
      "type":"wordcloud",
      "options":{
        "text":"hello angularjs istanbul russia dağ çççç Добрый вечер 你好",
        "step-angle":45,
        "step-radius":50
      }
     }
    ]
}
zingchart.render({ 
id : 'myChart', 
data : myConfig, 
height: "100%", 
width: "100%" 
});
```

Thanks for support team.

Answer (score 2):

We have fixed the issue with characters from other languages. You can reference your original example in the following snippet.

```js
var myConfig = {
  "graphset": [{
    "type": "wordcloud",
    "options": {
      "text": "hello angularjs istanbul russia dağ çççç Добрый вечер 你好",
      "step-angle": 45,
      "step-radius": 50
    }
  }]
};

zingchart.render({
  id: 'myChart',
  data: myConfig,
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%"
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#myChart {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src='https://cdn.zingchart.com/2.3.3/zingchart.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/2.3.3/modules/";
    ZC.LICENSE = ["569d52cefae586f634c54f86dc99e6a9", "ee6b7db5b51705a13dc2339db3edaf6d"];
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
</body>

</html>
```